# Is there a difference between "had you.." and "if you had.."?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Can you please explain if there is any difference between below 2 sentences?

- You could have easily found water **had you** put all your efforts in one place.
- You could have easily found water **if you had** put all your efforts in one place.

Source of info : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrtcFl-J9YE&t=545s

Comment: Sentence 1 sounds old fashioned or very formal. Sentence 2 is natural. Both are good English and have the exact same meaning.

Comment: can you please explain sentence 1 with an example?

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing. If you understand 2, you understand 1.